# Extract Field Names and Types from DBF Files

Tags: python, dbf

I have about 100 DBF's that I need to move to SQL Server. Rather than trying to recreate the entire structure manually, I'd like to be able to pull out the field names and field types from the DBF files and create the associated tables in SQL Server. I know the types will be different, but this isn't a problem, I can map those. I'm using DBFRead but can't figure out how to extract the field information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with `DBFRead`, but using my [`dbf` library](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/):

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table('some_table_here.dbf')
table.structure()
# ['test C(40)', 'test2 N(3,0)', 'test3 C(3)', 'test4 M']
```